# Image Segmentation in Hue color space

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have an image in HSV colour space. The Hue component spans from 0 to 255. I need to split those values to 8 bins and assign a specific colour to each bin rather than the range. As an example lets take the first bin as 0-31 and assign all pixels with the value 31 in that bin. Similarly for the bin with pixels 32-63 assign the value 63. This can be done using loops but it takes a considerable amount of time. Is there a way to perform this as matrix operations or built in numpy functions?

```
for i in range(image_lenth):
 for j in range(image_width):
   pixel_value = image[i][j]
   if(pixel_value >= 0 and pixel_value<=31):
     image[i][j] = 31
   elif(pixel_value >= 32 and pixel_value<=63):
     image[i][j] = 63 
   ...
```

Comment: You basically want to set the 5 least significant bits to 1. i.e. `bitwise_or` with `0x1F`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as Dan suggests in the comments:

```
x = np.arange(256)
x |= 31
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `numpy.array` so use (without `for`-loops)

```
img[( 0 <= img) & (img <= 31)] = 31
img[(32 <= img) & (img <= 63)] = 63
img[(64 <= img) & (img <= 95)] = 95
# etc.
```

Or using `for`-loop

```
for x in range(0, 256, 32):
    img[( x <= img) & (img <= x+31)] = x+31
    #print(x, x+31)
```